# text alignment inside a container in html

Tags: html, css

any solution for this? i want to align those texts below vertically.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFCcr.png)

here's my css codes

```
.d{ /* Sales Report Modules */
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        color: gray;
      }
      .e{ /* Sales Report Modules */
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: -20px;
        color: gray;
      }
      .f{ /* Sales Report Modules */
        text-align: right;
      
        margin-right: 10px;
        color: gray;
      }
```

i tried aligning the texts by using text align but it doesn't work

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant HTML code as well, preferably as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/2518285) which demonstrates the problem.